# How can I achieve this blue background used in Skype when selecting a friend in the list?

Tags: winforms, colors, skype

I suppose it's some king of gradient used, but I can't tell.
I'd like to use the same in my WinForms application.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to do something like this is to use a program like Paint.Net to get the RGB values of the colors used in the drawing.

Using a panel as an example:

```
void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
  e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

  using (LinearGradientBrush br = new LinearGradientBrush(
                                  panel1.ClientRectangle,
                                  Color.FromArgb(52, 151, 254),
                                  Color.FromArgb(61, 129, 243),
                                  LinearGradientMode.Vertical)) {
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, panel1.ClientRectangle);
  }

  using (Pen p = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(37, 110, 184), 2)) {
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(p, 0, 0,
                             panel1.ClientSize.Width - 1,
                             panel1.ClientSize.Height - 1);
  }
}
```

Results in:

[image]

Pretty close to the original.  You can make adjustments by lightening or darkening the colors used.